# Excel formats Date different after export from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms

When I want export the result set of a sql query from Management Studio to Excel, Excel does some inconsistent formatting to column with datetime values.

IN SSMS the Date looks like that in the first picture, and after exporting the values to Excel some rows are formatted different, like in the second picture.

[image: IN SSMS the Date looks like that]

[image]

I only have this problem with Excel, (Tools like Libre Office don´t have this issue), but on the system which I am working on, I am not allowed to install libre office. Any advice from an Excel pro?!

EDIT: SSMS is installed in German and Excel in English (thanks to my client), 
EDIT2: changed language settings, no effect

Thank you

Comment: Check your language settings in ssms and excel and make sure they match

Comment: Oh good idea. I will try to change my language settings

Comment: Booth are set to english now, no positive effect

Comment: Did you check us and uk?

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because data is exported as text, data types are ommited.
I develop [SSMSBoost add-in](http://www.ssmsboost.com). Alond many other tools it allows to copy-paste data to excel preserving datatypes. You can also script grid as .XML spreadsheet, which also preserves datatypes.

Hope this helps.